# Redirect Manager not coming up. How to clear out the table?

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5

I was using the Redirect Manager in Joomla 2.5 and there were thousands of links. Some very old notes. This is an site that has been running for 2 years without anyone looking at it. Anyway, many of the links had creation dates of 2 years ago. There were too many to redirect them all, and they looked like they were created with evil bots.

I delete a thousand of them, and not the Redirect Manager doesn't come up at all. I get a blank screen. I would like to just clear out the table entire and start fresh. Can I do this from MySQL? If so, which MySQL tables are there related to the links being stored for the Redirect Manager? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phpmyadmin you can simply empty the table #__redirect_links.